# How to use oAuth with ActionScript 3.0?

Tags: actionscript-3, twitter, air, oauth

I came across this oAuth library for ActionScript 3.0. http://code.google.com/p/oauth-as3/

It seems to have all that you need to do oAuth, but I can't make heads or tails of it. I've never worked with oAuth (or any authentication..) before and am not really sure how to use it. I can't find any examples of this specific library, or any in general concerning oAuth and AS3.

Would anyone mind walking me through (or directing me to a tutorial) concerning how to use oAuth to interact with Web API's? Specifically I'm looking for ActionScript 3.0 interacting with Twitter.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't usually like to post answers that just contain links but unfortunately, given the nature of the question and thus the answer, I think it's about the only choice here.

First I just want to say, try harder with googling next time. [Many results came up first try](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=seb&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&safe=active&sclient=psy-ab&q=oAuth%20Actionscript%203&oq=oAuth%20Actionscript%203&aq=f&aqi=g-v2&aql=1&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=1890l6314l0l6658l2l2l0l0l0l0l118l118l0.1l1l0&gs_l=hp.3..0i15l2.1890l6314l0l6658l2l2l0l0l0l0l118l118l0j1l1l0.cgsbsh.1&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=ab4a373e0b87ba5e&ix=seb&ion=1&biw=1430&bih=838).

Second, there seems to be two google code repositories for this. Just in case you're interested, here is a link to the second one (you provided a link to the first) http://code.google.com/p/oauthas3/. This repository has code which is newer than the repo you referenced.

Third, here are some links to articles/tutorials about this library which should provide all the help you've requested:

http://soenkerohde.com/2010/01/twitter-as3-oauth-lib-with-flex-4-example/
http://www.iotashan.com/index.php/2008/04/28/oauth-actionscript-library/

Note also this question and answer here on stackoverflow: [Pinless OAuth on Adobe AIR for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761238/pinless-oauth-on-adobe-air-for-android). It has some code and discussion about the library, so I've referenced it here as well.